# Checking whether differential operator maps vector space to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Given a vector space $V$ that is spanned by: $\{3^t, 2^{-t}\}$, can we conclude that the differential operator $\frac{d}{dt}$ maps $V$ onto itself?

It is my understanding that by looking at the basis for the vector space and seeing how the differential operator acts on each element within the basis, we can judge what it does to the entire space. So:

$\frac{d}{dt}(3^t) = 3^t \ln 3$ and $\frac{d}{dt}2^{-t}=-2^{-t}\ln 2$

Could we then justify that since $\ln3$ and $-\ln2$ are constants, the span of  $\{3^t \ln 3, -2^{-t}\ln 2\}$ would span $V,$ and therefore $\frac{d}{dt}$ would map $V$ onto itself?

Comment: That's completely valid, yes. (although it is important that we note here that the derivative is linear)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you can do it in a more formal way. $v\in V$ means that $$v=a\cdot3^t+b\cdot2^{-t},\ a,b\in\mathbb R$$
Then $$\frac d{dt}v=(a\ln 3)\cdot3^t+(-2b\ln 2)\cdot2^{-t}=a_13^t+b_12^{-t}\in V$$